# Python 3 Is it possible to reference a variable from outside a loop inside it (without a global)?

Tags: scope, python-3.6

```
def test():
    i = 0
    for e in range(5):
        i=+1
        print('i in for loop {}'.format(i))
        while True:
            print ('i in while {}'.format(i))
            break
test()
```

Tried a dictionary:

```
def test():
    ns = {}
    ns['i'] = 0
    for e in range(5):
        ns['i']=+1
        print('i in for loop {}'.format(ns['i']))
        while True:
            print ('i in while {}'.format(ns['i']))
            break
test()
```

And defining a an empty class:

```
class Namespace:pass
def test():
    ns = Namespace()
    ns.i = 0
    for e in range(5):
        ns.i =+1
        print('i in for loop {}'.format(ns.i))
        while True:
            print ('i in while {}'.format(ns,i))
            break
test()
```

Got this output:

```
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
```

wanted:

```
i in for loop 1
i in while 1
i in for loop 2
i in while 2
i in for loop 3
i in while 3
i in for loop 4
i in while 4
i in for loop 5
i in while 5
```

Are there work arounds, without resorting to `global`  so the 'i', that's referenced isn't local to each loop scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change i=+1 to i+=1 and you're good to go:)

Comment: Doh! Thanks Feel like such a fool!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code you meant to write `+=` but wrote `=+` which is equivalent to `=`.

Comment: Python does have `+=` syntax, here is a working snippet: https://repl.it/repls/AliveColossalLogin

Comment: You're right, maybe it wasn't there in 2.7 though? I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah yes, I think i mixed things up with' `++` and `--` that are not allowed, and should be replaced with `+=1` `-=1` :) it's been a while I haven't used python ! Thanks